# Prove that if the set B is in the finite union of the sets Ai, if p is limitpoint of B then p is limitpoint for at least one Ai.

Tags: real-analysis

I am not that familiar with writing proofs and would like some feedback checking if the steps in my proof are valid.

Problem statement,

Let $B_n = \bigcup _{i=1} ^n A_i, \quad Ai \in X $ and X is a metric space.

If p is a limit point of the set $B_n$ then p is a limit point of at least one of the sets $A_i$.

---

Proof:

Let p be a limit point of the set $B_n$ then for every open neighborhood around p there are points $p_{k} \in B_n$ distinct from p. Since all these points $p_n$ are in the finite union of the sets $A_i$ the point p must also be a limit point of at least one of the sets $A_i$, which proves the statement.

Does reasoning look ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a limit point of $B_n$. Assume $p$ is not a limit point of all $A_i$. Then there exist neighbourhoods $\{U_i\}$ of $p$ such that $(U_i\cap A_i)-\{p\}=\emptyset$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Set $$U=\bigcap U_i$$
This is a neighbourhood of $p$ such that $(U\cap A_i)-\{p\} =\emptyset$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ (Why?).

But this means that $p$ is not a limit point of $B_n$ since it is the union of $A_i$'s

A comment: I think the subscript in $B_n$ is unnecessary but that is a personal preference.

Comment: Right, I see that in my proof I think I'm done by concluding that there are infinitely many points in at least one of the sets Ai for every open neighborhood around p. But that does not imply that p belongs to the closure of some of the Ai:s.

Comment: The problem is these points could be taken from any of the $A_i$'s depending on the neighbourhood of $p$ you pick. The problem is that you want to show that for a particular $A_i$, all neighbourhoods of $p$ always intersect it at some other than $p$.